# How to instantiate a TypeMirror

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotation-processing

I have an AnnotationProcessor that reads spring webmvc annotations and generates code based on what it finds.

The code works great, but I need to figure out how to unit test a method that takes a `javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror` as an argument and spits back it's String type representation, including generics (e.g. `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>>` is an example of what it would return if I passed a `TypeMirror` representing a `Map<String, List<String>>` as an argument.

So in order to unit test this method (I based my code on this answer: 
[Getting the qualified class name of generic type with Java 6 annotation processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587211/getting-the-qualified-class-name-of-generic-type-with-java-6-annotation-processo)) I would like to either mock or create a TypeMirror during unit testing.

In my actual code I get the `TypeMirror` I need using `VariableElement.asType()`, but running a debugger leads me to discover that the actual implementation of VariableElement is a core Java class, not part of the api:
http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol$VarSymbol.html

And the TypeMirror impl is this, similarly buried in a non-public-facing part of the jdk:
http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$ClassType.html

I'd rather not go instantiating internal java types - what's the "right" way to instantiate a `TypeMirror` (or `VariableElement`)? Has anybody mocked one out where they could give me an example?

This is the method I want to unit test:

```
private void typeToString(final TypeMirror type, final StringBuilder result,
                          final char innerClassSeparator) {
    type.accept(new SimpleTypeVisitor7<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void visitDeclared(DeclaredType declaredType, Void v) {
            TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) declaredType.asElement();
            String rawType = rawTypeToString(typeElement, innerClassSeparator);
            result.append(Util.getUnqualifiedClassName(rawType));
            //java.lang.* is auto-included by the compiler for all classes
            if (!rawType.startsWith("java.lang")) {
                importTypes.add(rawType);
            }
            List<? extends TypeMirror> typeArguments = declaredType.getTypeArguments();
            if (!typeArguments.isEmpty()) {
                result.append("<");
                for (int i = 0; i < typeArguments.size(); i++) {
                    if (i != 0) {
                        result.append(", ");
                    }
                    typeToString(typeArguments.get(i), result, innerClassSeparator);
                }
                result.append(">");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visitPrimitive(PrimitiveType primitiveType, Void v) {
            result.append(box((PrimitiveType) type).getName());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visitArray(ArrayType arrayType, Void v) {
            TypeMirror type = arrayType.getComponentType();
            if (type instanceof PrimitiveType) {
                result.append(type.toString()); // Don't box, since this is an array.
            } else {
                typeToString(arrayType.getComponentType(), result, innerClassSeparator);
            }
            result.append("[]");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visitTypeVariable(TypeVariable typeVariable, Void v) {
            result.append(typeVariable.asElement().getSimpleName());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visitError(ErrorType errorType, Void v) {
            // Error type found, a type may not yet have been generated, but we need the type
            // so we can generate the correct code in anticipation of the type being available
            // to the compiler.

            // Paramterized types which don't exist are returned as an error type whose name is "<any>"
            if ("<any>".equals(errorType.toString())) {
                throw new CodeGenerationIncompleteException(
                        "Type reported as <any> is likely a not-yet generated parameterized type.");
            }
            result.append(errorType.toString());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void defaultAction(TypeMirror typeMirror, Void v) {
            result.append("void");
            return null;
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the general case, I'd say "it's an interface, so just create a mock."  For this case, I think you're testing the wrong seam.

The true unit under test in this case is your anonymously-declared `SimpleTypeVisitor` implementation.  Consider that to truly test the whole `typeToString` method, you would have to verify that all six methods that you've implemented are consistent with their expected behavior.  Therefore, you should promote the anonymous implementation to a concrete one and test those methods.  Each of them should have at least one test and in those tests you can mock out `typeToString` to deal with your recursive calls.