# Instantiating `TypeElement`s outside the processor context for unit testing

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

In my project, I have a few classes that operate on objects from the `java.compiler` module such as `TypeMirror`s and `Element`s. Typically, these classes are used by an annotation processor that has access to `ProcessingEnvironment` for fetching code `Element`s, but I'd like to be able to test those classes in isolation too. How can I obtain e.g. a `TypeElement` compiled from a mock java source file inside my test framework?

I'm aware that a similar question was asked here: [How to instantiate a TypeMirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554658/how-to-instantiate-a-typemirror), but the accepted answer doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: `TypeElement` is an interface, so you can create a mock implementation.

Comment: I could, but those elements represent quite complex structure of the source code and implementing all of that correctly in a mock would be difficult and error prone. I'd rather re-use existing java compiler to do that for me properly.