# How to check a methods parameter type in an Annotation Processor?

Tags: java, reflection, annotation-processing

With pure reflection this would be easy, but the annotation processor world seems to be different. How do I get from a `TypeMirror` returned by `getParameterTypes()` to `String.class`?

In my *Annotation Processor* I want to check if the currently visited method has exactly the form:

```
public boolean someName(String input)
```

I can check the primitive return type, but the `String` parameter makes problems:

```
private void processAnnotation(Element method, Messager msg) {
    final MyAnnotation ann = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
    if (method.getKind() != ElementKind.METHOD) {
      error("annotation only for methods", method);
    }
    Set<Modifier> modifiers = method.getModifiers();
    if(!modifiers.contains(Modifier.PUBLIC)) {
      error("annotated Element must be public", method);
    }
    if(modifiers.contains(Modifier.STATIC)) {
      error("annotated Element must not be static", method);
    }
    ExecutableType emeth = (ExecutableType)method.asType();
    if(!emeth.getReturnType().getKind().equals(TypeKind.BOOLEAN)) {
      error("annotated Element must have return type boolean", method);
    }
    if(emeth.getParameterTypes().size() != 1) {
      error("annotated Element must have exactly one parameter", method);
    } else {
      TypeMirror param0 = emeth.getParameterTypes().get(0);
      // TODO: check if param.get(0) is String
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385561/find-type-parameter-of-method-return-type-in-java-6-annotation-processor?rq=1

Comment: @RC. Nah, not "Type Parameter" (which has to do with generics) and there must be a simpler way then to write a full fledged tree visitor class. It#s probably just one method call and cast -- but which ones? Maybe through `declaredType.asElement()` or something? I don't want to compare the strings of the type names, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can go through [`Elements.getTypeElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getTypeElement-java.lang.CharSequence-) to retrieve a type during processing by its canonical name.

```
Types    types = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
Elements elems = processingEnv.getElementUtils();

TypeMirror param0 = m.getParameterTypes.get(0);
TypeMirror string = elems.getTypeElement("java.lang.String").asType();

boolean isSame = types.isSameType(param0, string);
```

There isn't a way to get a "class" as such, because annotation processing runs on a partial compilation and we can't load the classes which are being compiled.

Comment: I see. What do you think of the slight modification `elems.getTypeElement(String.class.getCanonicalName()).asType();`? Since in my scenario the type in question is an "always there type". Is this "safe"? One place less to make a typo...

Answer (score 2):

A simpler alternative would be :

Retrieve the parameters from the method

```
ExecutableElement myMethod;
List<VariableElement> myParameters = myMethod.getParameters();
```

Then check the type of each parameter (for example a string or a primitive type)

```
"java.lang.String".equals(myParameter.asType().toString())
myParameter.asType().getKind().isPrimitive()
```